# Iterating diagonally through a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d

I have to iterate through an 2D array of chars. I already have the code to iterate / but I'm lost when it comes to .

Here is my 2d array:

```
a,v,i,o,n,l
t,o,t,o,l,l
m,a,r,c,o,e
s,a,g,r,c,i
o,e,n,z,o,g
s,t,r,a,r,u
```

I already have:

```
a
tv
moi
....
```

and I need:

```
l
nl
ole
....
```

Here is the code to iterate / :

```
int size = 6;

for (int k = 0 ; k < size ; k++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= k ; j++) {
        int i = k - j;
        System.out.print( lista[i][j] + " " );
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for (int k = size - 2 ; k >= 0 ; k--) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= k ; j++) {
        int i = k - j;
        System.out.print(lista[size - j - 1][size - i - 1] + " " );
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Start with pen and paper. What the the indices of the items in each iteration? Is there a pattern? What is it?

Comment: I was using excel to try make up my mind. I think I do know the pattern but I failed to code it. In my case I have a n*n  matrix nand the patterns is: you start with your y at 5 and your x at 0, you have to decrease that 5 once per iteration and increase that 0 once per iteration too.  Until you reach 0 and 5 respectively.

Comment: Your pattern is not for a square matrix of size `n` but a square matrix of size `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] arr = {
                { 'a', 'v', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'l' }, 
                { 't', 'o', 't', 'o', 'l', 'l' },
                { 'm', 'a', 'r', 'c', 'o', 'e' }, 
                { 's', 'a', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'i' }, 
                { 'o', 'e', 'n', 'z', 'o', 'g' },
                { 's', 't', 'r', 'a', 'r', 'u' } };
        for (int n = -arr.length; n <= arr.length; n++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                if((i-n>=0)&&(i-n<arr.length)){
                    System.out.print(arr[i][i-n]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own code. The only thing you need to do is transpose your matrix first. I have written and tested it for you. myArray is the array you gave us as input and yourArray is the one you need to use in for your code as lista.

```
for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
       yourArray[5 - i][j] = myArray[j][i];
    }
}
```